# react-router-dom displays blank page for routes with more than one path segment "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Any time I create a route with more than one `"/"` (i.e. `"/testing/test"`) react just returns a blank page when it should return the `Test` component as well as the navigation bar and footer. In the example below the route `"/testing"` works as expected but `"/testing/test"` does not.

Here is my router:

```
<UserProvider>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/">
        <Route index element={<Grid />} />
        <Route path="testing">
          <Route index element={<Test />} />
          <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
    <Footer
      legal={threat_intel.bottom_disclaimer}
      lastUpdate={threat_intel["Data Last Update"]}
    />
  </BrowserRouter>
  <ToastContainer />
</UserProvider >
```

- React - v18.2.0
- react-router-dom - v6.16.0

Comment: @DrewReese I am using react-scripts to build and aws s3 bucket to host. It should be noted it also doesn't working in local development

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering a nested route with an invalid absolute path. It produces the following error:

> Error
>
> Absolute route path "/test" nested under path "/testing" is not valid.
> An absolute child route path must start with the combined path of all
> its parent routes.

Either fully quantify the route path, e.g. `<Route path="/testing/test" element={<Test />} />` or use a relative path, e.g. `<Route path="test" element={<Test />} />`.

Using relative paths is easier to read when nesting routes.

```
<UserProvider>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/">
        <Route index element={<Grid />} />         // "/"
        <Route path="testing">
          <Route index element={<Test />} />       // "/testing"
          <Route path="test" element={<Test />} /> // "/testing/test"
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
    <Footer
      legal={threat_intel.bottom_disclaimer}
      lastUpdate={threat_intel["Data Last Update"]}
    />
  </BrowserRouter>
  <ToastContainer />
</UserProvider>
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-displays-blank-page-for-routes-with-more-than-one-path-segment]

Comment: This fixes that error but "/testing/test" still does not render for me.

Comment: @charliewelch I added a running demo sandbox to my answer, but here also is a link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-displays-blank-page-for-routes-with-more-than-one-path-segment-6pxk7y?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: I see it works in your sandbox, I also tried creating a dummy program to test this and it worked as well. But for some reason it still doesn't work in my actual environment. I am still having "/testing" work fine but "/testing/test". And I changed things to be how you have it above. Could the UserProvider (useContext) affect anything?

Comment: @charliewelch I don't believe the context provider would change how routes are matched and rendered. You could certainly try commenting out other chunks of code to see if the issue goes away, and if so, go into *that* component and repeat until you find the suspect code.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a completely separate issue.Wrapped around my router I had an if statement that was returning false when I assumed it was returning true. I probably should have included that in my code block. But I was fetching a .json file with data in it and was using a relative path so when my url was "/testing/test" it was looking for the file under "/testing/{filename.json}"